# how to perform mysql replace with " ' "?

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE name SET name = REPLACE(student_name, 'a', ''');
```

By using the code above I want to update a to become '. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the `'` by using `\'`:

```
UPDATE name SET name = REPLACE(student_name, 'a', '\'');
```

Or use double-quote:

```
UPDATE name SET name = REPLACE(student_name, 'a', "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to include quote characters within a string:

```
“'” inside a string quoted with “'” may be written as “''”.

“"” inside a string quoted with “"” may be written as “""”.
```

Precede the quote character by an escape character (“\”).

> “'” inside a string quoted with “"” needs no special treatment and
>   need not be doubled or escaped. In the same way, “"” inside a string
>   quoted with “'” needs no special treatment.